# How to wait for user enter in vue input with v-model

Tags: vue.js

Code:

```
<input type = "number" min="10" max="90" value="50" v-model="preview_width"/>
```

My website changes width of 2 components depending on "preview_width value". When I change value in input, website moves and doesn't let user enter correct value in friendly way. And my question is: How to edit "preview_value" AFTER user press "Enter", or after he stop targeting this input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v-model` has a `.lazy` modifier, which will sync the data after change events:

```
<input type = "number" min="10" max="90" value="50" v-model.lazy="preview_width"/>
```

You can read the documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy

Answer (score 2):

You could use `lazy` to update the `v-model` only on change.

```
<input type = "number" min="10" max="90" value="50" v-model.lazy="preview_width"/>
```

or

```
<input type = "number" min="10" max="90" value="50" v-model="preview_width" lazy/>
```

Here is the doc: https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#lazy

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash debounce method, which will delay triggering of the method to update width.

```
<input v-on:input="onChangePreviewWidth">
...
methods: {
  onChangePreviewWidth: _.debounce(function (e) {
    this.preview_width = e.target.value;
  }, 500)
}
...
```